# cant understand how this function works $this->Auth->login() in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am new in cakephp. i am making a logging system in cakephp 2.x .. i am stuck here

**UsersController.php** extending AppController

```
 public function login()
{
   if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your email/password combination was incorrect');
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that it is not checking that whether the email and password typed by the  user is correct or not..and is logging the user in without checking .. i have never used the auth component before ... so i am feeling hard to grasp that how this function is checking the email and password from the database as on the internet and the cakephp website they are using this function to check whether the user has logged in successfully or not./i always used sql queries but i dont know how this component is working .. please correct this function and explain me where it is checking the email and password from the database

here is my 
**AppController**

```
  class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'admin'),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'admin'),
        'authError'=>"You can't access that page",
        'authorize'=>array('Controller') 
    )
);

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
  }

 public function beforeFilter() {
$this->Auth->allow('index');
```

}
}

Comment: as far as I know when you submit the form to action `login` with the username(or the fields that you define as username) and password, from variable in `$this->request->data` it takes the necessary info and checks from db(this is done by `login()` function of Auth component and this is the magic of that component), if the provided data is true `$this->Auth->login()` returns true, otherwise false.

Comment: @Davo thankyou.. but i am not taking the username from the user ..i am taking the email and password ..but it is not logging me in

Comment: have you specified this `$this->Auth->fields = array ('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password' );` in App controller, because by default the auth fields are `username` and `password`, and if you want `email, password` pair you should specify email as your username

Comment: ookkk thankyou i get it .. this is wat exactly i was missing

Comment: @Davo can you help me in this question i'll be very thankful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121118/auth-login-with-email-or-mobile-cakephp

Answer (score 1):

class AppController extends Controller {

```
    // added the debug toolkit
    // sessions support
    // authorization for login and logut redirect
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Cookie',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'),)),
            'authorize' => array('Controller'))
    );



    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

please replace the co in app controller.